# Fast Hankel Transform

Tags: calculus, integration, transformation

Can someone please explain what would be the expression for weights(Ho) in a Fast Hankel Transform.I found this in a paper and could not find any satisfactory answers .

[image]

Comment: it is the discretized version of $J_o(\lambda r)$

Comment: If this is a paper about math, $H_0$ should definitely be defined somewhere. Could you provide a link to the paper ?

Comment: I agree with previous posters, the question is very interesting, but needs more context.